# Insert concatenate or similar Function into my Index search

Tags: google-sheets

This is what I want to do
Working on its own

Formula A is

`=INDEX(WarframeMarketData!D3:D999,MATCH('Selling Warframes'!A3 ,WarframeMarketData!A2:A999,4))`

Formula B is

`=CONCATENATE(A2," ","Blueprint")`

Formula B: It needs to Replace A3 in my formula and add the Result of A2 + text Blueprint into the search

Comment: Keep in mind that we can't see what you are seeing. We know nothing about your spreadsheet, layout, data, data types, locale, etc.—all of which are important in order to answer a specific question. I suggest you share a link to the spreadsheet (or to a copy of it) so that the volunteer contributors here can see everything.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)
As Erik suggested, you may want to consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _manually entered_ desired results there.